# ALL IIS sites on box now challenge/response

Tags: iis

I have a dev server that I just went back to after a few months (2003 R2, IIS 6), and all of a sudden my local sites I run on there for development and testing are challenging me for credentials when anonymous is turned on for all of them. It also does not accept any credentials, even the local administrator.

These are not .NET sites.

Any ideas how this could have happened and how I can fix it?

Answer (score 0):

When you select Anonymous Access, you have to type the credentials of a user to run under.  Are you sure the credentials there are valid?  Sometimes if you have an expired password on that account and don't change it, behavior like this could happen.

Another thing to check related to this is to make sure that user has sufficient privileges to the folders and resources configured for your site(s).

Comment: I changed the password and ensured it was set never to expire and not allowed to be changed, and then went to IIS and changed it at the top level as well as the individual sites with no change in symptom.